# Java 8 - How to reduce the size (lines) of this map operation?

Tags: java

I need to get value map for a key, if its not there create new map and insert the key/value. How can i  reduce the number of lines of this operation using java 8 ?

```
Map<String, Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
Map<String, String> valueMap = map.get(key_1);
if(valueMap == null) {
    valueMap = new HashMap();
} 
valueMap.put(key_2, value);
map.put(key_1, valueMap);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `computeIfAbsent` method of Map [See The Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key_1, k -> new HashMap<>()).put(key_2, value);
```

Note that you won't need to create a new HashMap instance (unlike getOrDefault method for example), if there is a key, only if there is nothing (corresponds to `if(valueMap == null)` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation for `Map`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

It looks like `computeIfAbsent` does what you want.

First, declare a function `newMap()` that simply returns a `new HashMap()`. Then:

```java
Map<String, Map<String, String> map = new HashMap();
map.computeIfAbsent(key_1, newMap);
map.get(key_1).put(key_2, value);
```

EDIT: Rather than declaring a named function `newMap`, you can use an anonymous function `k -> new HashMap<>()`, as suggested in [Mark Bramnik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63846876/3080723).

Do **not** use `.putIfAbsent(key_1, new HashMap())`, or `.getOrDefault`, or any other non-lazy function that would evaluate its default value even if the default value is not needed. These functions are appropriate if the default value is a simple value, for instance an `int`; they are not appropriate if the default value requires a call to `new` to be built.